# wordpress sticky menu scroll issue - browser window size?

Tags: wordpress, scroll, sticky

I'm trying to fix an issue that I think is related to the Wordpress sticky menu issue. This page shows the issue in question: http://kitchpickleball.com/product-category/usopencollection/performance-ss-crews-usopencollection/

In Chrome and using the mouse wheel to scroll down, this page shows different types of behavior based on the size of the browser window.

a) If I have the browser window sized (vertically) so that only one row of products is visible, the behavior is as expected. The page will scroll all the way to the footer, and the sticky menu is displayed.

b) If I have the browser window sized so that both rows of products are just barely visible, the content flashes before I get to the footer. (And sometimes, I am not even able to *get* to the footer.) The sticky menu at the top never becomes visible.

I have seen a number of proposed solutions to the issue (assuming that the issue is a sticky menu issue), but haven't fully understood them all. I'm fairly well versed in CSS, but not so much in JS. One solution that I did understand was to make the header and the sticky header the same size, but that hasn't solved the issue in my case. I'm hoping somebody out there can give me a hand. Would be much appreciated!

Comment: what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite this css and try.

```
     #masthead.stuck {
        top: 0px !important;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 100;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
```